# Element slides up and down repeatedly on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a scroll to top button that appears when a user has scrolled to a certain point. I created [a CodePen that works](https://codepen.io/mattmc318/pen/povGbQW), but my regular code doesn't; the button slides up and down repeatedly. I've tried adding a debounce variable like in the following code, but that just makes it show and then hide. Could this be a jQuery bug?

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // Show scroll to top button on page scroll
  let $scrollToTop = $('#scrollToTop');
  let debounce = false;
  $('#content').on('resize orientationchange scroll', function () {
    const position = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(position);

    if (position >= 100 && !debounce) {
      debounce = true;
      $scrollToTop.slideDown(500, function () {debounce = false});
    } else if (position < 100 && !debounce) {
      debounce = true;
      $scrollToTop.slideUp(500, function () {debounce = false});
    }
  });
});
```

**Edit**

[Mozilla recommends using CSS whenever possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects), can I do that in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend going the `scroll-behavior: smooth` method and just use a traditional `<a href="#content">` approach. You can detect Safari and use `window.requestAnimationFrame` to code the animation yourself - it saves you a lot of jQuery bloat/bugs.

Feel free to [read about `scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) in the MDN docs or watch [this quick YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNNr7TU7XcU).